# MySQL - order by a column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have those two tables:

Table 1: **option_value**

```
| option_value_id | option_id | sort_order |
|=================|===========|============|
| 1               | 1         | 1          |
| 2               | 1         | 2          |
| 3               | 1         | 3          |
```

Table 2: **option_value_description**

```
| option_value_id | option_id | name   |
|=================|===========|========|
| 1               | 1         | Small  |
| 2               | 1         | Medium |
| 3               | 1         | Large  |
```

And this code is sorting the results according the "sort_order" values from the "Table 1":

```
$option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value WHERE option_id = '" . (int)$option_id . "' ORDER BY sort_order ASC");
```

How can I keep the same code for showing the results, but sort the results by "name" from the Table 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` query so you will JOIN your tables and you will be able to order by column `name` of second table

```
$option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value a LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description b ON a.option_id = b.option_id AND a.option_value_id = b.option_value_id WHERE a.option_id = '" . (int)$option_id . "' ORDER BY v.name ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` the two tables on the option_value_id field:

```
select ovd.*
from option_value ov
   join option_value_description ovd on ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id
where ov.option_id = ?
order by ovd.name
```